# Routes regex constraint not working as expected with subgroup in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, routes

I have the following constraint:

```
get '/:name' => "products#show", :as => :product, :constraints => {name: /\w+(-\w+)*/}
```

The following URL:

```
/aa--aa
```

Will return a `No route matches [GET] "/aa--aa"`

But if I do `/\w+(-\w+)*/.match('aa--aa')` I will get a MatchData object.  So, how does Rails handles Regex constraints? Why is this not being consistent with `.match`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails will embed your constraint as this:

```
/\A#{tests[key]}\Z/ === parts[key]
```

See this: [formatter](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb#L119)

That's why this won't pass.

Answer (score 0):

The `^\w+(-\w+)*$` regex *cannot* match `aa--aa`, because dashes need to be separated by words.

I don't know Ruby but I suppose `^` and `$` are implicit in your constraints, and I guess you're getting a result for the `aa` substring because the anchors are no longer implied (I may be totally wrong here).

I suggest the following pattern:

```
\w+(?:-+\w+)*
```

I just added a `+` quantifier to the dash, and made the group non-capturing.